# How do I place a line in the middle of a list item?

Tags: list, line

I would like to have a line in the middle of my list-items for a menu:

Regular 12oz. _____________________________ $1.

I tried using "border-bottom" but that doesn't look right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text-decoration property to add a line to your text.

```xml
<li><a href="#">Regular 12oz. <span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1.</span></a></li>
```